# Getting Unknown browser query `dead` when run npm run dev

Tags: vue.js, npm, laravel-5

when I run `npm run dev` getting

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `dead`
at D:\Data\Project\posm-admin\node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:164:11
```

Project is using Laravel with Vue. This project is bit old one.

below is the package json

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.21",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.4.1",
        "admin-lte": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
        "codeflask": "^1.2.1",
        "cropperjs": "^1.4.3",
        "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
        "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
        "dropzone": "^5.5.1",
        "fuse.js": "^3.3.0",
        "fuzzyset.js": "0.0.7",
        "idb-keyval": "^3.1.0",
        "jquery-confirm": "^3.3.2",
        "keycode": "^2.2.0",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.4.1",
        "lottie-web": "^5.4.3",
        "moment": "^2.22.2",
        "plyr": "^3.4.7",
        "pusher-js": "^4.3.1",
        "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
        "select2-bootstrap-theme": "0.1.0-beta.10",
        "velocity-animate": "^1.5.2",
        "vform": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-async-computed": "^3.5.0",
        "vue-awesome": "^2.3.8",
        "vue-chat-scroll": "^1.3.3",
        "vue-clipboard2": "^0.2.1",
        "vue-image-compare2": "^0.7.2",
        "vue-input-autowidth": "^1.0.2",
        "vue-json-excel": "^0.2.96",
        "vue-list-rendered": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.8",
        "vue-ls": "^3.2.0",
        "vue-multiselect": "^2.1.3",
        "vue-notif": "^1.1.10",
        "vue-notification": "^1.3.13",
        "vue-prism-editor": "^0.1.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
        "vue-tables-2": "^1.4.70",
        "vue-tippy": "^1.0.0",
        "vue-touch": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
        "vue2-datatable-component": "^2.3.1",
        "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.1.5",
        "vue2-filters": "^0.4.1",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.16.0"
    }
}
```